# python calculate slope raster from DEM

Tags: python, gis

I need the slope for 4 points in austria. I have the coordinates and the DEM (from opendata Austria). I found this tutorial (https://www.earthdatascience.org/tutorials/get-slope-aspect-from-digital-elevation-model/) and tried the code. But the results that I get are values like 30000.788 ... that cannot be degree? do I miss a transformation into meter?
I use this code:

```
import richdem as rd
shasta_dem = rd.LoadGDAL(f'{project_data}dem_au.tif')
slope = rd.TerrainAttribute(shasta_dem, attrib='slope_riserun')
rd.SaveGDAL(f'{project_data}dem_slope.tif', slope)
```

the picture looks great, but the values... I do not understand them!
[image: Slope-Map for Austria]

The Dem has values from 105 to 3736, if that would be meter it is correct for Austria, but in the describtion it says the DEM scale units are degrees?
[image: DEM Austria]
Can someone explain that to me,please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope  In short: *slope* is not an angle, it is the factor between horizontal and vertical distance. (Note road signals have a different convention).

Comment: yes, I know, I need the slope in degree, but why such high values?

Comment: https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_api.html#richdem.TerrainAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original question the issue was likely with the scale. In `richdem` you can use the `zscale` [argument](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_api.html#richdem.TerrainAttribute) when the pixel resolution unit does not match the elevation unit, for example with the pixel resolution is in degrees (lat/lon) and the elevation unit is in meters.

Here is an explanation from the same function in [gdal](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html#slope).

> If the horizontal unit of the source DEM is degrees (e.g Lat/Long WGS84 projection), you can use scale=111120 if the vertical units are meters (or scale=370400 if they are in feet).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to calculate the slope! The problem was the DEM. It had strange dimensions, with another, more precise DEM from open data it worked fine : )